# MATLAB:How to copy contents from a file into a particular position of an old file

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have two text files: file1.txt & file2.txt

*Contents of file1.txt:*

```
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;


My old contents(1);
My old contents(2);
My old contents(3);
My old contents(4);


Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
Required contents of file;
```

*Contents of file2.txt:*

```
My new var(1);
My new var(2);
My new var(3);
My new var(4);
```

*I have an updateFile.m function:* which is trying to replace the old contents from file1.txt with new var respectively

```
function updateFile(file)

% Read the new contents
fid = fopen('file2.txt', 'r');
c1 = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));
newVars = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
newVars = newVars{1};

% Save the testfile in to a cellaray variable
fid = fopen(file, 'r');
c2 = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));
oldContent = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');


% Search for specific strings
oldContentFound = strfind(oldContent{1},'My old contents(1);');
oldContentRowNo = find(~cellfun('isempty',oldContentFound));

% Move the file position marker to the correct line
fid = fopen(file, 'r+');
c3 = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));
for k=1:(oldContentRowNo-1)
    fgetl(fid);
end

% Call fseek between read and write operations
fseek(fid, 0, 'cof');

for idx = 1:length(newVars)
    fprintf(fid, [newVars{idx} '\n']);
end

end
```

The problem I am facing is that, file1.txt still contains some old contents which are not required. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some characters into the file but you can't remove some. You have to erase your file with a new one that has the correct content.

Here is a rewriting of your function that does the job:

```
function updateFile(file)

% Read the new contents
fid = fopen('file2.txt', 'r');
newVars = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
newVars = newVars{1};

% Read the old content
fid = fopen(file, 'r');
f1 = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);
f1 = f1{1};

% Find pattern start line
[~,k] = ismember('My old contents(1);', f1);

% Replace pattern
for i = 1:numel(newVars)
    f1{k+i-1} = newVars{i};
end

% Replace initial file
fid = fopen(file, 'w');
cellfun(@(x) fprintf(fid, '%s\n', x), f1);
fclose(fid);
```

Best,

Comment: Smooth... :) Works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

File access is inherently byte-based.  There's no such thing as inserting or deleting content at the middle of a file.  In most cases, the easiest approach is to edit the content in memory, then rewrite the entire file.

In your case, after reading the input file, find the start and end rows in the cell array, and simply replace them with the new data.  Then open your file again for normal writing, and output the entire cell array.